# what is the difference between keypress event and real keyboard key press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I fill a form field with the following code, but It doesn't change ng-pristine to ng-dirty.

```
$("#username").keypress(function(event) {
var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
$('#username').val($('#username').val() + String.fromCharCode(key));
});
$('#username').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 77}));
```

is there any function that exactly simulate a real keyboard key press?

Comment: `jQuery` events and `Angular` events don't mix. If you want to do this simulation use something like Protractor or Selenium

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two things here - the difference between a keypress and a real user originating keyPress and there's why your code isn't working.

#### Why your code isn't working

Let's start with why your code isn't working - Angular knows how to update its DOM through something called the digest cycle. It does this by having every Angular system function schedule a digest if one is not already in progress.

Your code needs to simulate this by calling `$rootSCope.$apply()`.

Also, consider not manipulating the DOM with jQuery but using Angular instead for the task - change the *value* #username is binding to in the controller scope.

#### As for the difference

One is a trusted DOM event and the other is not - although that's not a big deal or the causing factor of your issue. Some interactions with the DOM will not happen when you trigger an event but will happen with a real user interaction - this is a security feature that does not kick into play here.

Comment: can call `$apply()` on any scope object, not just `$rootScope`

Comment: Most important take-away here, for the original problem: "Also, consider not manipulating the DOM with jQuery".

Comment: @DRobinson I completely agree, but I try not to make presumptions about what OP is doing - for example if he's testing or scraping a website that might not be possible. charlietfl that's also a good comment, upvoted, if he _can_ access a scope object he should definitely not cause an app-wide digest cycle.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I didn't understand what to do. I'm trying to fill an input using firebug, so what shall I do ?

Comment: @Salman trigger a `$rootScope.$apply` on the Angular app. You can also do `angular.element($("#username")).scope().$apply()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this link :

http://inching.org/2014/08/19/javascript-key-event-simulate/

this one simulates exact real key press.